# Assignment "target_list" applications in Python?

Tags: python, list, arguments, variable-assignment

I knew about *target_lists* in *assignments* and *for loops*...

```
from pprint import pprint

poker_hand = {1: "9h", 2: "Jh", 3: "Qh", 4: "Kh", 5: "Ah"}

value, suit = poker_hand[1]
print "First card:", dict(value=value, suit=suit)

for key, (value, suit) in poker_hand.iteritems():
    print key, value, suit
```

But to see them available in as function arguments was a pleasant surprise.

```
def tl_args(a, b, c, (d, e, f, g), (h, i, j, k, l)):
    return locals()

pprint(tl_args(1, 2, 3, (4, 5, 6, 7), (8, 7, 9, 10, 11)))
```

Output:

```
First card: {'value': '9', 'suit': 'h'}
1 9 h
2 J h
3 Q h
4 K h
5 A h
```

As a function argument:

```
{'.3': (4, 5, 6, 7),
 '.4': (8, 7, 9, 10, 11),
 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3,
 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7,
 'h': 8, 'i': 7, 'j': 9, 'k': 10, 'l': 11}
```

Does this behaviour continue in Python 2.7.+? Is there a blog (or PEP) somewhere reviewing applications of "target lists" in Python?

FYI: For this example I tested Python 2.6.6.  This might explain the ".3" and ".4" arguments appearing!?  (What are these "dot" arguments called and are these defined in any PEP?)

For basic details... cf. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-target_list

Comment: What you're describing in the function-argument case is called "tuple argument unpacking" and it was removed in Python 3.

Comment: ThanX, given it's name I just found [PEP 3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

Comment: @NevilleDNZ You may want to read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) as well.

Comment: Awesome PEP 3113 link. Is "tuple argument unpacking" unique to Ye ol' þython? ... "tuple argument unpacking" would appear to be a crude type of argument checking.  eg. (runtime) checking the argument is a list, and of the correct length.  No doubt it is "þythonic" to have minimal argument/type checking.  Hurts my head to wonder how it handles a generator/iterator...